# Getting entire iOS stack traces/crash logs through Google Analytics

Tags: ios, exception, google-analytics

What I'm basically looking for is iOS's equivalent to Android's Google Analytics [Exception Reporter/Exception Parser](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions#exception-reporter).

On Android, [these enable me to detect uncaught exception and receive the entire stack trace/crash log for each crash on the Crashes and Exceptions section of Analytics' web UI](http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-analytics-easytracker-detailed.html).

However, [on iOS these don't seem to be available](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/exceptions) and I seem to be stuck with the severely incomplete stack traces that appear in their place.

Am I stuck with the incomplete descriptions I get on Google Analytics? I know there are other options such as Flightpath that do provide these logs, so is my only option using one of those, or does the Analytics iOS SDK have some function somewhere I have yet to find that would enable me to get access to the full logs?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm curious as well.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. Seems like the only valid solution, as I mentioned in my original post is using some other service such as Flightpath.

Comment: Also need this, lame that Google can't give you full stack trace on exceptions in iOS.

Comment: I suppose there stil is no Easytracker for iOS v2 GA?